# How to save an binary image to any format to on my pc

Tags: c#

How to save an image( saved as binary in DB) from a picturebox to jpg or any format to be saved on my pc...
what the code should be written on the button save?

Comment: You should be more specific when saying DB. Also, you may want to show some progress you already did.
Anyway, this link may help you: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27846062/convert-blob-to-jpg-and-update-blob

Comment: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8946846/converting-a-byte-array-to-png-jpg) is your answer if you want to convert byte array to png...

Answer (score 1):

You may check this link:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33310/C-Save-and-Load-Image-from-Database

They descried the process. :)