# I have tinyBlob datatype in databse, what should be correspoding data type while writing pojo?

Tags: java, mysql, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee

I have tinyBlob data-type in my mysql database, i am willing to store images in that ,now i have to write pojo class for that. what shall be the corresponding data-type?

Thanking You in advance!

Comment: Better approach is to save the image on hard drive or even AWS s3. An usual approach is to save the images like `{primary-key}-{some constant-string}.jpg`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert Blob to JPG and update blob](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27846062/convert-blob-to-jpg-and-update-blob)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `byte[]`. If you're going to save image or file then you have to convert byte array.

Answer (score 0):

Byte array is what you are looking for I believe.