# Java BLOB to image file

Tags: java, image, blob

I have a [`Blob`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Blob.html) object retrieved from a MySQL database by calling [`ResultSet.getBlob`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getBlob(int)).

```
Blob imageBlob;
while (rs.next()) {
    imageBlob= rs.getBlob("face");
}
```

after that my `imageBlob` is something like this: `data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhE................`

I've been googling around but I haven't found any solution to my problem: how do I create an image file and save it on the disk from this BLOB?

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27846062/convert-blob-to-jpg-and-update-blob

Comment: First convert Blob to BufferedImage then BufferedImage to Image...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`imageBlob` is storing the base64 representation of your image data. For storing that onto your disk you need to decode that base64 representation into the original binary format representation.

```
// Imports required
import java.util.Base64
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

String imageData = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhE....";
String base64Data = imageData.split(",")[1]

byte[] decodedBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(base64Data);
ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(decodedBytes);
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(bis);

File outputFile = new File("output.png");
ImageIO.write(image, "png", outputFile);
```

Comment: works perfectly and easy to understand, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

First convert the Blob to BuffededImage:

```
Blob aBlob = rs.getBlob("Photo");
InputStream is = aBlob.getBinaryStream(1, aBlob.length());
BufferedImage image=ImageIO.read(is);
```

Then BufferedImage to Image:

```
try {
    // Retrieve Image
    File outputfile = new File("saved.png");
    ImageIO.write(image, "png", outputfile); // Write the Buffered Image into an output file
    Image image  = ImageIO.read(new File("saved.png")); // Opening again as an Image
} catch (IOException e) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: This is unnecessarily complicated, it's just a bunch of bytes which can be written to disk.

Comment: @RobinGreen, I know its not a good solution but its workable.