# How to write PNG image file from BLOB?

Tags: java, image, file, blob

I got this code to create and write a file from `Oracle BLOB` to `PNG` image file

```
try {
    final File file = new File("C:/Users/John.Doe/Desktop/PDF Templates/POC/output/" + pdfObject.getFileName());
    final FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(file);

    fileWriter.write(pdfObject.getContent());  << a String of the PNG content, see below:
    fileWriter.flush();
    fileWriter.close();
} catch (final IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**PNG File content:**

```
�PNG

IHDR<binary code> .....
```

After i'm running this code, the image is not created well, means that, when i'm trying to open it using `Microsoft Photos` it says: "It looks like we don't support this file format"

Also, the original file size is less then the new one that being created with the code above.

What i'm doing wrong here ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java BLOB to image file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50427495/java-blob-to-image-file)

Comment: what do you mean with "*a String of the PNG content*"?

Comment: Maybe specify an `MIME` type for your `fileWriter`

Comment: To write binary data you would use a Stream, not a Writer. The latter is for character data. Also, what's the type of `pdfObject.getContent()`?

Comment: the `pdfObject.getContent()`is type of String

Comment: Is there a method that gives you a byte array?

Comment: @roeygol maybe `pdfObject.getContent()` is the base64 encoding of the image bytes

Comment: What is the type of `pdfObject`?

Comment: @roeygol can you provide a link to your file so when can see exactly what you have?

Answer (score 1):

A png image is not human readable text, and it gets corrupted if you try to represent it as a string and use FileWriter.

Instead your should get the content of the blob as an array of bytes or as an InputStream, and use FileOutputStream to write it to a file.

Comment: for more detailed help you should update the question with the exact type of `pdfObject`. Clearly it's not [java.sql.Blob](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Blob.html) because it has this "getContent" method.